# Is there a Cloud Based User Credential Service out There?

Tags: authentication, soa, registration, credentials

Anyone know of a service oriented membership provider / service? I’m looking for a hosted solution that provides user registration and authentication services. Basically I don’t want to deal with managing user credentials for my applications. I’d rather leave that to a service that specializes in that. Anything like that out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can just use OpenId: http://openid.net/

Answer (score 0):

[OpenID](http://openid.net/) or Facebook Connect suitable for your project?

Comment: openId works for people that already have accounts with other sites (providers). What I'm really looking for is something I can use to register my own (private) users for my application.

Comment: Ah. That sentence should be in the question ;)